# Sub-routes in Main route not getting static files ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have this directory structure

[image: DIRECTORY STRUCTURE]

Inside users.js I have routing for /login and /register. 
So I can access it by localhost:3000/user/login, but my static files containing CSS arent loaded.

How can I serve static files for all subroutes?

Comment: use the built-in middle ware function express.static and point to the directory where the static files are stored.you may refer [link](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)  eg : app.use(express.static('public'))

Comment: I have used that.

Comment: where are your static files stored?

Comment: @ZiyadAhmad In public/ folder

Comment: try `app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/../public))`

Comment: Thank you very much @ZiyadAhmad that worked. Post it as an answer and I'll vote it solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a trailing slash after `__dirname` followed by the relative path for the folder.

use path to normalize `.` or `..` in the folder path.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname + '/../public')));
```

Refer below link for more examples https://millermedeiros.github.io/mdoc/examples/node_api/doc/path.html#path.normalize

Answer (score 3):

Your page is located another level deep, so you have to add another couple dots.

Before: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">`

After: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../stylesheets/style.css">`

Comment: I use this to serve static files: app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: @Vishnudev What I'm saying is, when you use these assets in your views (html/pug/ejs), you need to change your path. I've edited my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: The problem  here is I use express and there is only one main page where I load the CSS. So when I do what you say, the problem is solved half way that my /users/login (Multilevel routes) are getting CSS but those having /home (Single level route) aren't

Comment: Which view engine are you using?

Comment: Express JS is my view engine

Answer (score 1):

write: (ex) (make the href or the src absolute path instead of a relative path) By adding **/** at the beginning of the path

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```

before :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/style.css">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/style.css">
```